# How do I hide singularity squashfs partitions in Nautilus

Tags: partitioning, nautilus

Notice the 2.5GB and 5.1GB volumes shown below, they are singularity mounted instances. I don't remember seeing them on 18.04 nautilus, but I do see them in 20.04 (Fresh install). Is there any option in gnome-disks to hide partitions? How do I hide all such partitions mounted by singularity?

PS: I also wish I can hide thinclient_drives :p which I see in RDP sessions.

[image]

Comment: Do you see these volumes in the disks app? If so click the gear button, click edit mount options and unselect Show in user interface.

Comment: But the problem is I will have to do this every time I mount an image in singularity. Is there a way to switch it off altogether for any image with certain params i.e. in my case squashfs partitions?

Comment: However you mount the partitions you just need to add “x-gvfs-hide” (no quotes) to your other mount options. This works with the mount command or in fstab. There are some examples here https://github.com/GNOME/gvfs/blob/master/monitor/udisks2/what-is-shown.txt